Why is complex derivative of $1/z$ gives delta function?
The complex derivatives defined as
$$\partial\equiv\frac{\partial}{\partial z}=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_{x}-i\partial_{y});~~\bar{\partial}\equiv\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_{x}+i\partial_{y})$$
satisfy the following relation
$$\partial \frac{1}{\bar{z}}=\bar{\partial} \frac{1}{z}=2\pi\delta^{(2)}(z).$$
How do I understand this relation intuitively and how to prove this mathematically?

Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Essentially, this comes from Stokes theorem
$$
\int_R d^2 z \partial_{\bar z} f(z,{\bar z}) = - i \oint_{\partial R} dz f(z,{\bar z})
$$
If $f(z,{\bar z}) = \frac{1}{z}$ and $R$ is any region containing the origin $z=0$, then
$$
\int_R d^2 z \partial_{\bar z} \frac{1}{z} = - i\oint_{\partial R} dz \frac{1}{z} = 2\pi  
$$
This implies that we must have
$$
\partial_{\bar z} \frac{1}{z} = 2\pi \delta^2(z).
$$
Another way to see this is to note the property
$$
\partial_{\bar z}\frac{{\bar z}}{z {\bar z}+\epsilon^2} = \frac{\epsilon^2}{(z{\bar z}+\epsilon^2)^2}
$$
Let us now take the $\epsilon \to 0$ of the above. The LHS reduces to $\frac{1}{z}$. The RHS vanishes except when $z=0$. We therefore have
$$
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{\epsilon^2}{(z{\bar z}+\epsilon^2)^2} = a \delta^2(z)
$$
We can fix the constant $a$ by integrating both sides over a disc of radius $R$
$$
a = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int d^2 z \frac{\epsilon^2}{(z{\bar z}+\epsilon^2)^2} = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_0^R 2 dr r \int_0^{2\pi} d \theta \frac{\epsilon^2}{(r^2+\epsilon^2)^2} = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{2\pi R^2}{R^2 + \epsilon^2} = 2\pi .
$$
